# undefined local variable or method `div' for #<#<Class:0x10923faf0>:0x109226b18>

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble with this as I get started with Ruby On Rails. Any help would be great. Additional info:
Extracted source (around line #25):

```
</header>
    <div class="container">
        <% flash.each do |key, value| %>
            <%= content_tag(div, value, :class=> "alert alert-#{key}") %>
        <% end %>
        <%= yield %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

The line should be `<%= content_tag(:div, value, :class=> "alert alert-#{key}") %>`

Notice I'm passing in a symbol :div instead of just div. The error just means its trying to look for a variable or method named div but content tag accepts a symbol or string I believe. I think it will work with "div" as well.

Comment: I will vote up once I get 15 reputation points....looks like that's needed before I can. Thanks again.